# Ways to reduce Vgs range of Logic Level MOSFET

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, switches, timing

I try to control two [MOSFETs](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BSS138-D.PDF) from one microcontroller pin, where one MOSFET shall turn on 400 ms after the first one. The second MOSFET is switching on a relay coil.

My idea was just to use a RC circuit on the Gate of the one to turn on secondly but unfortunately the range of Vgs is to huge to exacty determine the turn on point of the MOSFET.

Can the simple RC and MOSFET circuit be altered, so that the turn on Point can be precisely defined? (+- 50ms)

The goal is a small component count and a robustness against temperature and tolerances.

Comment: Note that Vgs_threshold is where the MOSFET just *barely* starts to turn on in the technical sense but is effectively still off as far as you are concerned if you are interested in using it as a switch. That's why we apply square waves to the MOSFET so we can race past the region where the MOSFET is operating as a linear device. I say this because you may need to rethink your definitions which would cause you to rethink your approach as a lone RC circuit to delay something by 50ms will also spend a similar amount of time transitioning into the ON state on top of that. Turn on is fuzzy.

Comment: My answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543854/how-to-build-ac-current-sensor-circuit-for-esp-01-gpio/543966#543966) includes a schematic describing exactly this. Click the simulate link and tinker with it.

Comment: @DKNguyen Good Point about the linear region! This means that I would need a circuit which creates the delay and a circuit which turns on the transistor rapidly. Do you have and suggestions?

Comment: A comparator driving the next MOSFET's gate with the the RC at one input and a resistive divider to set the threshold at the other input is probably simplest.

Comment: 400ms is a really long time.  Especially if you don't require a precise 400ms a one shot delay chip and a bit of logic may not be out of the question.  Turning a mosfet on slowly over half a second sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the simple RC and MOSFET circuit be altered, so that the turn on
> Point can be precisely defined? (+- 50ms)

Yes, but you will have to add a component that has more accurate threshold voltage. An op amp or comparator could be used with reference voltage set by a voltage divider, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfspI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Don't you need something to drain the capacitor when it turns off so the delay will work on the next on cycle?

Comment: Turn off delay was not specified. I assume @Thauer has the RC delay set up appropriately (with a diode across the resistor to turn off quicker if that is desired).

Comment: Oh I see it just drains slowly back through the MCU.  So the circuit would have to be turned off for .75s or a second before you turned it on again.  That's not as bad as I was thinking.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott Thanks for the solution. I am going to put a diode and small resistor across R3 so that i am able to turn off quickly but not stress my microcontroller to much by capacitor rush currents.

Answer (score 0):

Utilise a MOSFET driver that can provide sufficient current to turn on the MOSFET in datasheet stated time, and along with a timer chip, this should work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly easy to get an iron-clad guaranteed +/-10%-ish tolerance with a very simple circuit, even the timing capacitor alone will likely have a 5% or worse tolerance (especially if you count temperature, voltage coefficient and aging of a ceramic cap).

If you have control of the firmware, it's far, far, far better to use another pin and have a second output. Internal clock is typically fine for that, a crystal or resonator even more so.

If you can guarantee that the input to the time delay will remain low for a "long time" (seconds) before the next time it goes  high then you may be able to use a simple RC circuit with an analog comparator eg. LM393. Putting a diode across the R can speed up the circuit somewhat, but a 1% tolerance (remember 5% at least is allotted to the capacitor) and a 63% of Vcc trigger means that things have to be stable and noise-free to within couple mV on a 3.3V system.